# DropdownList With Data Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net

This is my DropdownList :

```
                        <div class="editor-label">
    <p>
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gov) %>
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    <p>
        <%=Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Gov, ViewBag.gov as SelectList)%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gov) %>
    </p>
```

and this is my view controller :

```
        public ActionResult TestR()
    {
        ViewBag.gov = new SelectList(entity.gouvernerat, "Idgov", "Nomg");
        return View();
    }
```

With HttpPost :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestR(LogModel.preRegister Model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (LogModel.preRegister.Verifuser(Model.IDag))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Agence existe deja");
                return View(Model);
            }
            else
            {
                int ins = LogModel.preRegister.Register(Model);
                if (ins > 0)
                {

                    return View("Index");
                }
                else return View();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

Now Dropdown list show me the list of Gov in my DB(that's what i want), but when i clic on create i got this error in my DropdownLisrt `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable <SelectListItem>' with key 'Gov'.`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297399/populating-asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy with LINQ to SQL.  Let's say you have a table `Govs` that contains your "Tunis", "Ariana", etc. strings.  You can then create your select list like this:

```
govs.Select( x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Name } );
```

Of course you can even be more flexible and assign the value to something else, like an ID.

**Update:** more details to answer questions posed in comments:

Add the select list items in the view model:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GovItems { get; set; }
```

Then, in the controller, before returning your view:

```
// database code to get "Govs" table goes here....

var vm = new MyViewModel {
  GovItems = govs.Select( x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Name } );
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( x => x.Gov, Model.Govs )
```

I hope this helps.  If you're still confused, I recommend reading some tutorials about ASP.NET MVC.  I recommend Microsoft's official one:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs

Comment: Whare i put it in ModelClass Or Controller

Comment: I usually set things up in the controller, but you could make an argument for putting it in a view model.  It certainly doesn't belong in a model since it's presentation-specific.

Comment: How to put it in Controler ? i can't do it sorry but i'm beginner in ASP.net MVC this is my first project

Comment: Chlebta, please read the tutorial I referenced at the bottom of my answer, I think you need it.  You just put it in the controller by...putting it in the controller.  I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: You should have two actions in your controller: one for the `HttpGet`, one for `HttpPost`.  Could you update the answer with the `HttpPost` action?

Comment: Thanks, looking now.  `HttpGet` is the default option if you don't specify it.

Comment: You're not setting `ViewBag.gov` in your `HttpPost` action.  So when you return `View()`, it isn't available, which is why you're getting that error.  Set `ViewBag.gov` in your `HttpPost` action, and that should clear that error.