# How to create Html.DropDownList or Html.DropDownListFor from a strongly typed model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, html-helper

I have a strongly typed model.

```
@model IPACS.Models.IPACS_Departments
```

This model has a `departmentID, name, description, owner.`

I need to populate a DropDownList from this model but I'm not sure how?

I want the value to be the `departmentID` and the text to be `name`.

Here is the model I am using.

Is my model the problem then?

public IPACS_Departments()
        {
            this.IPACS_Functions = new HashSet();
            this.IPACS_Document = new HashSet();
        }

```
    [Key]public int departmentID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<IPACS_Functions> IPACS_Functions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IPACS_Document> IPACS_Document { get; set; }
```

I've tried the syntax in the answer below but it won't compile.

My model.departmentID, model.name, model.description, model.owner I'm not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: dropdownlist should have multiple options, not just text. or did i misunderstood something?

Comment: He probably means his model holds a list of departements with beforementioned fields. @James: You'll have to populate a `SelectList` with the data and use that with the `DropDownListFor`. Refer to answers below or look for examples with this knowledge for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of posts and documentation on this. Here is something that can help you:

[Populating ASP.NET MVC DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297399/populating-asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist)

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.YourId, new SelectList(Model.YourList, "ValuePath", "TextPath"))%>
```

Comment: I read through some examples and my model or something must be wrong because the syntax doens't work on my end.

Comment: you are usin razor. replace <%=  with @. and remove %>

Comment: Yeah I had already done that.  But it always gives me the red squiggly lines saying it doesn't like about 4 different things.  Really hate to have to use a viewbag for this, but it seems so much simpler to use a viewbag.